# htaccess file to allow request on images from remote domain

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

I have a webserver with processed images in a directory. I would like to use these images on an other domain in html  tags. On the remote site, the images do not show up. But when I access the image with the URL in the browser, it works.

I tried the following htaccess content:

```
<FilesMatch \.(jpg|png|gif)$>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But the images still don't show on the remote domain.
What settings are needed to make images accesible from another domain?

Comment: "the images do not show up" - what is the HTTP response when requested from the other domain?

Comment: @MrWhite the error is 504 Gateway Timeout

Comment: The problem was apparently that the requesting server had https while the server with the image had http.
Adding https to the image server solved the problem.

Comment: "But when I access the image with the URL in the browser, it works." - so you were presumably requesting a different URL in the browser (http as opposed to https)?

Comment: Yes the problem was a mix between http and https servers and Chrome does not allow mixed content.